# How to get TextField for password for FindElement() funcion in Selenium 2

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriver

```
<div>
<input id="Email-hidden" class="hidden" type="email" autocomplete="off" readonly="" value="" spellcheck="false" name="Email">
<label class="hidden-label" for="Passwd">Hasło</label>
<input id="Passwd" class="" type="password" placeholder="Hasło" name="Passwd">
</div>
```

I'm using FireFoxDriver. 
I tried `IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='Passwd']"));` and also with "*" instead of "input"

I've done it with email, but i can't get into the password text field
Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

[Look what textfield i Mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Zb5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot refers to google login page. The page is using some kind of javascript/ajax, thus the password element will not available instantly, and you need to wait until it's available. It's advised to use `WebDriverWait`.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); // after 10 seconds we will throw timeout-exception
var element = wait.Until(wd => wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='Passwd']")));
element.SendKeys("password is here");
```